# Can't export fields from certain pdfs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, batch-processing, acrobat

I have a directory of 30 or so pdf files, and 10 of them won't export their fields to a text file for me.

I'm using the Javascript Editor in Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 in the Batch processing portion of the program.

The program is very simiple it looks like this:

```
var fname = this.documentFileName;
this.exportAsText(true, null, fname + ".txt");
```

When I run it with the 10 files selected I should be getting a text file that has the same name as the document processed, but instead all I get is an error log that reads `Warning: no documents were processed`

It doesn't give me any other reasons why I do not end up with an output file.

I ran pdfinfo on a file that generated the results and a file that did not, they look pretty much the same and neither is encrypted:

One that didn't work:

```
Creator:        Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0.6)
Producer:       Adobe PDF Library 9.0
CreationDate:   Tue Dec  7 15:58:15 2010
ModDate:        Mon Jun  3 12:11:12 2013
Tagged:         no
Pages:          5
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      405476 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.6
```

---

One that worked:

```
Creator:        Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0.6)
Producer:       Adobe PDF Library 9.0
CreationDate:   Tue Dec  7 15:58:15 2010
ModDate:        Wed Jun 12 08:44:05 2013
Tagged:         no
Pages:          5
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      300702 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.6
```

The only difference between them seems to be the field values.

Comment: Password protected PDFs?

Comment: @stanlyF When I open them they don't appear to be password protected, but I don't claim to know everything about PDFs either, they're a pretty broad topic.  I just know when I open the files I'm not asked for a password.  Also I appear to be able to edit them manually and save a copy without any issues.

Comment: Would using a tool like `peepdf.py` help?